# 'make' not recognized within VSCode, "The term 'make' is not recognized"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile, mingw-w64

I'm trying to debug my MinGW-64 C++ program in Visual Studio Code, but I'm having a lot of trouble even building it because VSCode isn't recognizing `make`. I have a makefile that I build from with no problem from the command line. I'm using the following `tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately, I get this error upon building:

```
make : The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path 
is correct and try again.
```

So, how can I use my makefile to build (and then debug) my program in Visual Studio Code?

---

[What I've tried so far]

I have checked the settings for the Makefile Tools extension, and have confirmed that both my Makefile Path and Make Path are set:

*Makefile: Makefile Path*

`[Project directory]\src\Makefile`

*Makefile: Make Path*

`[...]\msys\mingw64\bin\mingw32-make.exe`

I have also confirmed that typing both `make` and `[...]\msys\mingw64\bin\mingw32-make.exe` work equivalently well on my command line, so the path to the make program is correct. Maybe there's another path within vscode that I have to set that I don't know about.

Comment: Msys/mingw64 normally setup an fake environment. If you want to use make from commandline, add it to the PATH. But I would switch to cmake and use the add-ons cmake-tools and clangd. The cmake tools will find your toolkit and probably set ups the environment. With that it is also extremely easy to swap to clang or msvc.

Answer (score 0):

try to specify the full path to the file instead of `"command": "make"`. `"command":"[...]\msys\mingw64\bin\mingw32-make.exe"`.

Comment: It ended up being that `.exe` that was doing me in. Upon including that in the `"command"` field I was able to use either the full path or the relative one that uses the system path. I hadn't realized that VSCode uses Windows Powershell, so I played around in an actual Powershell window until I figured it out.